# get-pip.py error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, openstack

What is wrong here? I am trying to install `openstack-ansible` and this is look like pip related issue, all i found this in google and not sure its related to my issue or not https://bugs.launchpad.net/openstack-ansible/+bug/1779534, I am no way python expert to understand what is command doing and what is this error for, looking for hint or clue

```
[root@ostack-log-01 opt]# python -V
Python 2.7.5
[root@ostack-log-01 opt]#
[root@ostack-log-01 opt]# pip -V
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
[root@ostack-log-01 opt]#
[root@ostack-log-01 opt]#
[root@ostack-log-01 opt]# python /opt/get-pip.py --constraint /opt/global-requirement-pins.txt --constraint http://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt?id=60d840183f0665483e942649e5bc3e4f6ecbbad3 pip setuptools wheel
Ignoring jsbeautifier: markers "python_version=='3.4'" don't match your environment
Ignoring jsbeautifier: markers "python_version=='3.5'" don't match your environment
Ignoring hyperframe: markers "python_version=='3.4'" don't match your environment
Ignoring hyperframe: markers "python_version=='3.5'" don't match your environment
Ignoring cssutils: markers "python_version=='3.4'" don't match your environment
Ignoring cssutils: markers "python_version=='3.5'" don't match your environment
Ignoring kaitaistruct: markers "python_version=='3.4'" don't match your environment
Ignoring kaitaistruct: markers "python_version=='3.5'" don't match your environment
Ignoring tornado: markers "python_version=='3.4'" don't match your environment
Ignoring tornado: markers "python_version=='3.5'" don't match your environment
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpGNAU6j/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/tmp/tmpGNAU6j/pip.zip/pip/commands/install.py", line 282, in run
    wheel_cache
  File "/tmp/tmpGNAU6j/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 266, in populate_requirement_set
    requirement_set.add_requirement(req)
  File "/tmp/tmpGNAU6j/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 267, in add_requirement
    return result
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
[root@ostack-log-01 opt]#
```

Comment: If you already have `pip`, why are you running `get-pip.py`?

Comment: its part of upgrade process of openstack-ansible https://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ansible/pike/user/minor-upgrade.html

Comment: I found issue `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/3.2/get-pip.py` had this issue, after changing to `3.3` it works `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/3.3/get-pip.py`